# how i can upload a paid app to android market from egypt

Tags: upload

I want to upload a paid app to andriod market from egypt, they told me that support is not available for egypt for paid apps. can anybody tell me how i can do that and what is alternative to that.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regional app store policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move
   Probably not viable, but this is the perfect solution.
2. Make a free version, and from there link to your own site where you can sell an activation code, no purchase goes through Google. 
   Might be a violation of TOS, I don't see why it would but I'd take a look into it before you take this route.
3. Ignore the store altogether. 
   Just sell the APK from your own site. Not a great option as it's hard for customer to find your app.
4. Make an account in another country, not sure if this is legal, and almost certainly against TOS. If you have family in other countries you could "sell" your source to them, have them publish it and send your 100% "commission" back.

I would seriously check with a lawyer before taking #4.

I'd go with #2 if it isn't a violation of TOS. Makes it a bit of a pain, but if the app store can't sell paid apps in egypt, then likely the population is used to making purchases outside of the app store.

(Disclaimer: I'm an android dev in Canada, and I have no knowledge of the laws or google policies in Egypt)

HTH

Comment: so i can redirect to my site for paid version or slideme.org...it should be ok?

Comment: Technically there's no reason that wouldn't work. Might even help sales if you have a limited version and used it to drive sales to your full/paid version.